# I don't know how to return relevant data all the time SQL

Tags: sql-server

I don't know how can i return relevant data every time.

Hi guys, i'm working on an interactive web map where i display different object as marker on the map, like vehicules or fire hydrant. I'm getting the data from  M SQL server. Im using geoserver to generate JSON from sql view, i use these jsons to place marker and fill the popup with information about the object.

So for the fire hydrant i have 4 column in my view concerning the adress. two are user input in a software, and the other two come from data recovering from an other older software. 
like so
view:

```
╔═══════════╦══════════╦═══════╦═══════╗                                                                                                 
║ Adress1   ║ adress2  ║ NVOIE ║ TVOIE ║                           
╠═══════════╬══════════╬═══════╬═══════╣             
║           ║next to...║ Cesar ║ plaza ║                       
║Grand road ║in front  ║ Gand  ║ road  ║                   
║Winter road║          ║       ║       ║              
║Beer road  ║close to  ║       ║       ║                    
║  farm X   ║          ║       ║       ║                    
║ behind... ║          ║ Wine  ║ road  ║                      
║           ║          ║       ║       ║               
║           ║          ║       ║       ║                         
╚═══════════╩══════════╩═══════╩═══════╝    




SELECT
COALESCE (pe.adresse2, '') AS adresse2,
COALESCE (pe.Adresse1, '') AS Adresse1,
COALESCE(ad.NOM_VOIE,'') as NVOIE,
COALESCE (STUFF((SELECT     ',' + tv.libelle 
  FROM         [DDSRV3].[PV].dbo.TYPE_VOIE tv, [DDSRV3].[PV].dbo.ADRESSE ad
  WHERE     (pe.ADRESSE_REF = ad.CLE AND ad.TYPE_VOIE = tv.CLE) FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''),'') AS TVOIE
FROM  dbo.PE_ENTRETIEN en LEFT JOIN
      dbo.PE_POINT_EAU pe ON pe.CLE = en.POINT_EAU LEFT JOIN
      dbo.ADRESSE ad ON pe.ADRESSE_REF = ad.CLE LEFT JOIN
      dbo.TYPE_VOIE tv ON ad.TYPE_VOIE = tv.CLE
```

Here is a portion of the query i use to generate the view.

Adresse1 and Adresse2 (observation field) are user input Nvoie is name of the road and Tvoie is the type of road.
The problem here is that i don't know how to return the most relevant data as there is 4 or 5 different case. I'd like to check if the data in Adresse1 is equal to NVOIE + TVOIE, and if yes replace data in Adresse1 by ''. So at the end i should have the type of road then the name and last the observation.

expected result is when displaying in the pop up, I want adresse is : 12 Cesar plaza 70000 Vesoul next to the cemetary so: adress road number + road name + road type + postcode + City + observation field. i already have postcode city and road number. My problem is the data is doubled on some row, so if i display like this ill get sometimes 12 Cesar plaza Cesar plaza 70000 Vesoul.

Most relevant data is in this case the maximum data with no doublet.

Comment: Sample data and expected results are going to really help here. You can "simplify" the data however, it needs to be **representative** of the data you have. If you can, please do supply the sample data as DDL and DML statements, however, the expected results are fine being formatted `text`. With the data, Also explain how we tell what the "most relevant data" is.

Comment: You don't need to put the real data. Like I said, just **sample** data that is **representative** of your real data is fine, along with the expected result for that data and an explanation of what the "most relevant data" is.

Comment: Hi, i didn't want to put real data as in adresse2 (observation field) there is sometimes people name and phone number. Expected result is when displaying in the pop up, I want adresse is : 12  Cesar plaza 70000 Vesoul next to the cemetary so: adress road number + road name + road type + postcode + City + observation field. i already have postcode city and road number. My problem is the data is doubled on some row, so if i display like this ill get sometimes 12  Cesar plaza  Cesar plaza 70000 Vesoul.

Comment: most relevant data is having the maximum of data without having twice the same. As some times there is no user inputed data. Im sorry it's hard for me to explain what i mean in english, i'm trying to edit the tab in the post to be more representative.

Comment: The comments are not the place for unformatted data. As I said, the best thing is DDL and DML statements; and please don't forget those expected results.

Comment: I'm sure this data doesn't change much. I suggest you don't use hideous queries to clean it on the fly. Clean it properly and permanently and save it a nicer format

Comment: sorry i'm new here, i've read about DDL and DML statement but i don't get how it would help here, i've edited the post, with more representative data.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you have to use CASE sentence and a SubQuery:

```
    SELECT *,
           CASE WHEN Adresse1 = NVOIE + TVOIE THEN '' ELSE Adresse1 END AS Adresse1_Amended
FROM (
    SELECT
    COALESCE (pe.adresse2, '') AS adresse2,
    COALESCE (pe.Adresse1, '') AS Adresse1,
    COALESCE(ad.NOM_VOIE,'') as NVOIE,
    COALESCE (STUFF((SELECT     ',' + tv.libelle 
      FROM         [DDSRV3].[PV].dbo.TYPE_VOIE tv, [DDSRV3].[PV].dbo.ADRESSE ad
      WHERE     (pe.ADRESSE_REF = ad.CLE AND ad.TYPE_VOIE = tv.CLE) FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''),'') AS TVOIE
    FROM  [DDSRV3].[PV].dbo.PE_ENTRETIEN en LEFT JOIN
          [DDSRV3].[PV].dbo.PE_POINT_EAU pe ON pe.CLE = en.POINT_EAU LEFT JOIN
          [DDSRV3].[PV].dbo.ADRESSE ad ON pe.ADRESSE_REF = ad.CLE LEFT JOIN
          [DDSRV3].[PV].dbo.TYPE_VOIE tv ON ad.TYPE_VOIE = tv.CLE
) AS T1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer i'll search about that, and try to implemment it.